# Beamer sequential uncover for TOC two columns

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, columns, sidebar

I divided TOC into two columns, but I can't get it to appear sequentially (the lines in both columns appear at the same time).

I saw a solution using the "multicol" package, however with this package there is no way to choose the breaks and I want only the first section on the left and the remaining sections on the right.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
%\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball numbered]
%\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\huge}


\graphicspath{{./Figuras/}} 
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

%sidebar
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\useoutertheme[left, height=0pt, width=2cm]{sidebar}


%=========================================================================
\title[]{Título título título }
\author[Autor]{Autor Autor Autor}
\institute[Instituto]{\\ Instituto Instituto Instituto }
\date[2020]{25 de Dezembro de 2020}

%=========================================================================
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    
        \hspace*{-1.5cm}\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
            \titlepage}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        
        \hspace*{-1.5cm}\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{   
            \frametitle{Sumário}
            \begin{columns}[t]
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections, sections={1-1}]
                \end{column}
                
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, pausesections,pausesubsections, sections={2-}]
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
        }
    \end{frame}
    
    %=========================================================================
    %=========================================================================
    \section{Introdução}
    
    \subsection{Análise}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
        
        Texto A
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Processamento}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
        
        Texto B
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Redes}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto C
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Máquinass}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
        
        Texto C
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Métricas}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto D
    \end{frame}
    %=========================================================================
    %=========================================================================
    \section{Materiais}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto E
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto E
    \end{frame}
    %=========================================================================
    %=========================================================================
    \section{Resultados}
    
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto F
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Título}
        
        Texto F
    \end{frame}
    %=========================================================================
    %=========================================================================
    \section{Conclusões}
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto G
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Título}
    
        Texto G
    \end{frame}
    %=========================================================================
    %=========================================================================
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another problem is with the use of the frame title. I would like it to be left aligned (with the first column). Originally this frame had a sidebar, I removed it, but the frame still uses the space of the sidebar as if it existed. I used the **\hspace** command to shift the text a little to the left. The column text moves, but the frame title does not.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: @BambOo ok, I added the complete code